# Adequacy of logit model with oversampled data

Tags: logistic, classification, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, goodness-of-fit

I fitted a binary logit model with unbalanced data which were oversampled 
using SMOTE. This gave an excellent  ROC curve but very poor 
adequacy - the zero hypothesis of adequacy was rejected by Hosmer-Lemeshow test 
and le Cessie – van Houwelingen – Copas – Hosmer unweighted sum of squares test. 
However, the logit model for the original data (without oversampling) had 
very good adequacy statistics (but mediocre classification properties).

Are there any ways to oversample data without ruining adequacy statistics for 
a binary logit/probit model?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to your intercept term, which reflects the base rates. You trained the model on base rates that don’t reflect reality, so it needs to be corrected. Here is a paper discussing the problem and solutions
[king & zeng](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/0s.pdf)

Comment: SMOTE is an invalid statistical technique.  Under no circumstances should you use it.   Never under- or over-sample data you have already sampled.  Over and under-sampling is only appropriate when obtaining the data in the first place, if cost is an issue.  The development of SMOTE was an attempt to deal with improper accuracy scoring rules.  Two wrongs do not make a right.  See http://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage .